# C# KeyValue foreach column in row

Tags: c#, mysql

I am here today trying to work out how I can do this. I have the code below to look through each column in a DataRow, but how can I access the key AND value? I want to assign it to a dictionary in the class but I can't seem to get both of them, the only way I can get anything is by calling:

```
var columnValue = playerDataRow[column];
```

Here is the full thing:

```
using (var mysqlConnection = Sirius.GetServer().GetDatabaseManager().GetConnection())
{
    mysqlConnection.SetQuery("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `auth_ticket` = @authTicket LIMIT 1");
    mysqlConnection.AddParameter("authTicket", authTicket);

    var playerDataTable = mysqlConnection.GetTable();

    foreach (DataRow playerDataRow in playerDataTable.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn column in playerDataTable.Columns)
        {
            var columnValue = playerDataRow[column];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: might want to specify how you intend to use that `Dictionary` by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (DataRow playerDataRow in playerDataTable.Rows)
{
    var myDic = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    foreach (DataColumn column in playerDataTable.Columns)
    {
        myDic.Add(column.ColumnName, playerDataRow[column]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the variable column will be the key and the value will be columnValue

Answer (score 0):

looks that you only want one row of output - perhaps for this specific user based on `auth_ticket`

here is an example of how to get all values for this row into a Dictionary of strings (I'm converting all data to strings by the way just for this example)

```
var htRowValues = new Dictionary<string,string>();
using (var mysqlConnection = Sirius.GetServer().GetDatabaseManager().GetConnection())
{
    mysqlConnection.SetQuery("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `auth_ticket` = @authTicket LIMIT 1");
    mysqlConnection.AddParameter("authTicket", authTicket);

    var playerDataTable = mysqlConnection.GetTable();

    foreach (DataRow playerDataRow in playerDataTable.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn column in playerDataTable.Columns)
        {
            var columnValue = playerDataRow[column];
            htRowValues[column.ColumnName]=System.Convert.ToString(columnValue);
        }
    }
}
```

now you have all column values in the dictionary for this one row of data.